# Get roles by name in a 'guildMemberAdd' handler

Tags: oop, discord.js

Since member.guild.roles.get('roleName') no longer works. I'd like to know if there's an alternative to it.
message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'My Role Name') is not an option, since I don't have access to message object inside the 'guildMemberAdd' handler.

My code works fine using the role id, but I'd like to make it usable for other servers.

** updating my question
This is my code:

```
const role1 = 'the id number here'; ---> this one I'd like to be by name 
const role2 = 'the id number here'); 
if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') { 
  member.roles.add(role1); 
} if (collected.first().emoji.name === ''){ 
  member.roles.add(role2); 
} else { return}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the guild from [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember)

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   // member.guild.roles.cache.find(...) - Callback similar to Array#find()
   // member.guild.roles.cache.get(...) - string id parameter only
});
```

Comment: Already tried that, But I get "e is not a function" error.
My idea is to have all the roles in variables to assign them later accordingly to the reactions.

Comment: What is `e`? Is the use of it related to your current question

Comment: I don't know what this 'e' means. If I use member.guild.roles.cache.find(...) I get this error. I've been trying to get the role by name and assign that to a variable so I could use it later.

Comment: Can you update your question to include your current code. Also ensure `...` is replaced by your *actual callback function*, the ellipse is just a placehold for the example

Comment: I'm so sorry. I just tested again and it's working fine. 
const role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'role'). I must have misspelled something.
Thanks for the help!